# Python3.9. I am trying to write an exception but get this error:TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, exception, python-unittest

What should I do to print something and continue running after catching the exception? How to do the best practice on that?
I am writing unit tests but first of all tried to test wrong query to DB Postgresql in main.

```
class Error(BaseException):
    """something"""
    pass

class MailMessage(Error):
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = None
c = MailMessage()
c.set_recs_for_mail_box() #just for connection
command_to_db = "SELECT *"
try:
    recs = c.execute_query(c.connection, command_to_db)
except Error():
    pass
```

This also doesn't work

```
class MailMessage(BaseException): #just 'Exception' doesn't work
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = None
c = MailMessage()
c.set_recs_for_mail_box() #just for connection
command_to_db = "SELECT *"
try:
    recs = c.execute_query(c.connection, command_to_db)
except SyntaxError():
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error is trying to catch an instance of Error with `except Error():`, when you should catch the class with `except Error`.

```py
class Error(BaseException):
    """something"""
    pass

try:
    raise Error()
except Error:  # here except Error(): causes TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
    print("raised an error")
```